# bash read variable based on value of a default variable in config.ini file using source

Tags: bash, variables, newline, ini

I would like to read my config file and get the value of the default printer. So in this example I would expect to return the result `Zebra_GK420D`.

My config.ini file as follows:

```
enable_printing=yes
default_printer=printer1
printer1=Zebra_GK420D
printer2=DYMO_LabelWriter_4XL
create_proof=yes
```

I use the following bash script:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  2
  3 #Define filename
  4 fConfig=config.ini
  5 
  6 #If file exists, read in variables.
  7 if test -f $fConfig ; then
  8         source $fConfig
  9 fi
 10 
 11 echo The default_printer is: ${default_printer%?}
 12 
 13 echo The name of the default_printer is: $(${default_printer%?})
```

When I run the script, it returns:

```
The default_printer is: printer1
./test.sh: line 13: printer1: command not found
```

How can I fix my bash script so that it returns the following:

```
The default_printer is: printer1
The name of the default_printer is: Zebra_GK420D
```

As a side note, since the config.ini file is hosted on a Windows drive each line is returned with `\r` at the end, so I'm using the `%?` to remove the last character of each line. The danger here is that the final line in the file does not have `\r` at the end. What can I use instead of `%?` to remove only `\r` as opposed to blindly removing the last character?

Thank you.

Comment: If you fix your config file so that it doesn't use DOS line endings, you can just use indirect parameter expansion: `${!default_printer}`. (Without fixing it, you just need two lines `tmp=${default_printer%?}; echo ${!tmp}`.)

Comment: You can specify the exact character to remove: `${default_printer%$'\r'}`. However, I would strongly recommend just fixing the file, rather than make the consumer deal with the carriage returns.

Comment: You could try process substitution to filter out carriage returns while sourcing the file: `source <(tr -d '\r' < $fConfig)`

Comment: I utilised both suggestions from @chepner and Cole Tierney - Thank you both very much indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the error message: command not found. Look at your line 13:

```
echo The name of the default_printer is: $(${default_printer%?})
```

`$(command)` is used in bash to get the output of a command. So you explicitly asked to execute the printer name as a command, and, predictably, the command does not exist. Try:

```
echo The name of the default_printer is: ${default_printer%?}
```